# generate random sounds on button click swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I have a list of .wav files starting from sound1.wav,sound2.wav,sound3.wav.... till sound20.wav 
 
I want to play a random sound whenever user touches a button. What methods should I use and how ?

Comment: Take an array, store sound file names into that array, use `arc4random` to get random indexes of that array and play accordingly.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the arc4random_uniform() and the AudioServicesPlaySystemSound() methods to implement what you want.

First of all you need to `import AudioToolbox`

make a function to generate the sounds and call it inside the `@IBAction` function

This is is how you do it :

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton){
    playSound() //calling the function
}

    func playSound(){
    //select random number i.e sound1,sound2,sound3...sound[n]
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(TotalSoundFiles))
    //create the sound
    if let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sound\(randomNumber + 1)", withExtension: ".wav"){
        var mySound: SystemSoundID = 0
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL as CFURL, &mySound)
        //Play the sound
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the user presses the button, run the following code:

In swift 4.2 it is as simple as:

```
let sound = arrayOfSounds.randomElement()
```

In earlier versions:

```
let randIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(20)) // Random number between 0 and 20
let sound = arrayOfSounds[randIndex]
```

Then play the sound using AVAudioPlayer or any other method you want (such as SpriteKit if you are making a game).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution: a `playSound()` function that you call when the button is pressed

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

var player: AVAudioPlayer?

func playSound() {
    //generate a random Int between 0 and 19, and then add 1
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(20)) + 1
    //Construct the sound file name
    let randomSoundName = "sound" + String(random) + ".wav"

    //Then check that the file is in the app bundle
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: randomSoundName, withExtension: "wav") else { return }

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)



        /* The following line is required for the player to work on iOS 11. Change the file type accordingly*/
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.wav.rawValue)

        /* iOS 10 and earlier require the following line:
         player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeWAVE) */

        guard let player = player else { return }

        player.play()

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```